# Jetty-9 HTTP/2 in OSGi container. Cannot load a HttpFieldPreEncoder implementation for HTTP/2 over ServiceLoader

Tags: osgi, http2, jetty-9, serviceloader

recently I'm trying to call a REST-service, published over Apache-CXF. Everything is embedded in an Equinox 3.11.0 with Jetty 9.4.1.

Container starts Jetty, configured for HTTP/2:

```
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.4.1.v20170120
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6f89f665{/,jar:file:///C:/workspaces/com.ebase.eox/cnf/generated/fw/org.eclipse.osgi/12/0/bundleFile!/,AVAILABLE}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@187eb9a8{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1, h2c]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory - x509=X509@1517f633(jetty,h=[],w=[]) for SslContextFactory@4fe01803(bundleentry://12.fwk1276261147/jettyhome/etc/keystore,bundleentry://12.fwk1276261147/jettyhome/etc/keystore)
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@3015db78{SSL,[ssl, alpn, h2, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8443}
```

Wenn i call a REST-Service over https/ssl i get an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.PreEncodedHttpField.putTo(PreEncodedHttpField.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.hpack.HpackEncoder.encode(HpackEncoder.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.hpack.HpackEncoder.encode(HpackEncoder.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.generator.HeadersGenerator.generateHeaders(HeadersGenerator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.generator.HeadersGenerator.generate(HeadersGenerator.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.generator.Generator.control(Generator.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Session$ControlEntry.generate(HTTP2Session.java:1143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Flusher.process(HTTP2Flusher.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Session.frame(HTTP2Session.java:676)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Session.frames(HTTP2Session.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Stream.headers(HTTP2Stream.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.server.HttpTransportOverHTTP2.commit(HttpTransportOverHTTP2.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.server.HttpTransportOverHTTP2.send(HttpTransportOverHTTP2.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:218)
    ... 61 more
```

It seems (i have proven it), that **PreEncodedHttpField** cannot load all Implementations of HttpFieldPreEncoder over **ServiceLoader**.

```
    Iterator<HttpFieldPreEncoder> iter = ServiceLoader.load(HttpFieldPreEncoder.class,PreEncodedHttpField.class.getClassLoader()).iterator();
```

ServiceLoader sees only a **Http1FieldPreEncoder**, which is in the same Bundle as **PreEncodedHttpField**, so observable for a BundleClassLoader. This Implementation is registerd under Index "0".

In my case, it should be used an HTTP/2 Implementation **HpackFieldPreEncoder**, which bundle in http2-hpack, but not visible for **ServiceLoader**

Is there any workaround to make this second implementation visible for PreEncodedHttpField to avoid my Exception?

Thank you

Comment: Its a bug. I've raised this: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1290

Comment: Thank you for a quick solution.